# Django URL regex inconsistencies Local vs Apache

Tags: regex, django, apache, django-urls

I understand that verbose urls are better but I have an issue.

Consider this url:

```
url(r'^foobar/county/(?P<county_id>[\d]*)/year/(?P<year>[\d]*)/agent/(?P<employee_id>[\d]*)/objective/(?P<objective_id>[\d]*)[/]*$', foo_view, name='foobar'),
```

I would like to reverse it on the template with:

```
{% url 'foobar' objective_id=objective.id year=year county_id=county.id employee_id=employee.id %}
```

If any of the values are `None` then the url still works locally, witn `manage.py runserver`. The null value is skipped, e.g., when `county_id=None` the reversed url becomes `.../county//year/2030/...`.

But on apache this doesn't work. Apache does not recognize this as a valid url.

I realize that I could define different urls for each possibly null value, but how would I build the reverse on the template? I don't want to build a huge conditional just to reverse a url/

Comment: How does that work locally? I'd expect it to not work on either. What url would you expect to be matched

Comment: It matches the url, but leaves the parameter blank. Because the regex for each parameter ends with `*`. I give an example of the url above.

Comment: Ah right I think I understand now, but what does "doesn't work" entail? what errors do you get?

Comment: The standard no match 404: `The current URL, foobar/county//year/2016/agent/007/, didn't match any of these.`

Comment: What patterns does it try to match though? it should be able to pick up the [regex](http://regexr.com/3cv9e)

Comment: It tries to match all of them, and matches none of them. Particularly not the one in question. That is, using apache, `foobar/county//year/2016/agent/007/` doesn't match the url above. But it DOES match using `manage.py runserver`.

Comment: I've just realised the url you show in your [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870913/django-url-regex-inconsistencies-local-vs-apache?noredirect=1#comment59407505_35870913) doesn't have an `/objective/n`, so obviously it never would match that url, what I'm trying to say is that I think the problem is elsewhere

Comment: It still doesn't match if I include the objective id. The problem is the missing parameters that map to `//`. Apache is not handling them. I've tried all manner of permutations for several days.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105720/discussion-between-rob-l-and-sayse).